# 5 watt tube Amp has 2 8ohms outputs and I have 2 1x16ohm speakers. Can I connect them together?

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers, vacuum-tube

I have a Harley Benton GA5 head (5 watts tube amp head) which has two 8 ohms outputs.
I also have two 1x16 ohms cabs, one with a Celestion vintage 30 and one with an Eminence speaker.
Is it possible that I can connect both those cabs to the 8 ohm outputs without damaging at all the amp? I'm playing at home with low volumes.

Answer (score 3):

Doing so, you will not be able to enjoy the "full power" of your amp: because of the impedance mismatch, part of these 5W will no be transferred to the cabs. In the end you will get lower sound level that with using matched cabs (8 ohms) but this should not damage anything.

In the end, the amp will deliver less current than what it is made for…

Answer (score 1):

Wiring the two cabs in *parallel*, and connecting to one 8 Ohm output will make it match.

By connecting each cab to each output the amp won't be harmed - the load of 16 Ohms is greater than the 8 Ohms output. Were it 8 Ohms out into a 4 Ohms cab, it's not good.

Each cab to each output will result in the sound not being as loud, but that won't be an issue for your situation.